# Remove column nulls in Power Query without removing any actual values in any column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I want to take the table below that contains intermittent nulls and essentially collapse the table to be just a clean list of values in each column.  How can I do this in Power Query editor or possibly in Excel.  I don't care that the rows get rearranged.

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| null | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | null | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | null |

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |  |
|  |  |  |

Answer (score 2):

```
let
    Source = "Your source",
    Custom1 = Table.ToColumns( Source),
    Custom2 = List.Transform (Custom1, each List.RemoveItems(_,{null})),
    Custom3 = Table.FromColumns( Custom2, Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in
    Custom3
```

Comment: Hi David Sir, I was trying the solution posted. null is empty. So when I uploaded and pasted the m-code, it had no effect. so what i changed in the above instead of this `{""}`  used `{null}` and worked great and as is required in the OP as posted by user.

Comment: Good spot - I'll update the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the output in the transformation layer. Go to the Advance Query Editor of your table and add these new steps as below-

- replace the **your_previous_step_name** accordingly in the below script.

```
let
    //your existing steps in the table
    
    // new steps starts here
    //-------------------------------
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"your_previous_step_name", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Attribute=text, Value=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"I2",1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Attribute", "Value", "I2"}, {"Custom.Attribute", "Custom.Value", "Custom.I2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Custom.Attribute]), "Custom.Attribute", "Custom.Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Custom.I2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Output-

[image]